# How can I use other map identifier

Tags: map, wrapper-class

For my campaign I need some additional information form a custom object `PC_List__c`. In this list I have more information (e.g. salesrep) about the postcode.

I use a wrapper to collect the data of the campaign and map the pc information. If I have two `campaignmember` with the same postcode, both member merged. I know the problem is the `wrap.Acc_Pc` of the wrapper, but if I replace the `Acc_PC` with the `Id` of the `campaignmember`, I can't loop through the `pclist`, because the Id is not in the `pclist`.

How can I loop through the id of campaignmember and map to each pc of the member the BDM information of the pclist?

```
public class CampLetter {

    Private Id CamId {get; set;}
    Public List<ResultWrapper> resultList   {get; set;}

    public CampLetter () {
        
        CampLetter_go();
    }
    
    public class ResultWrapper {
        public Id           CampMem_Id                      {get; set;}
        public String       CampMem_Firstname               {get; set;}
        public String       CampMem_Lastname                {get; set;}
        public String       CampMem_Salutation              {get; set;}
        public String       Acc_Pc                          {get; set;}                  
    }
    
    public void campletter_go() {
        
        Map<String, ResultWrapper> mapPCToWrapper = new Map<String, ResultWrapper>();
        Set<String> PCNo = new Set<String>(); 
        CamId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');     
                
        for(Campaignmember CamM:[SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Salutation, Contact.Account.BillingPostalcode FROM Campaignmember WHERE CampaignId = :CamId and Status = 'selected']) {
            PCNo.add(CamM.Contact.Account.BillingPostalcode);
            ResultWrapper wrap              = new ResultWrapper();
            wrap.CampMem_Id                 = CamM.Id;
            wrap.CampMem_Firstname          = CamM.FirstName;
            wrap.CampMem_Lastname           = CamM.Lastname;
            wrap.CampMem_Salutation         = CamM.Salutation;
            wrap.Acc_Pc                     = CamM.Contact.Account.BillingPostalCode;
            
            mapPCToWrapper.put(wrap.Acc_Pc, wrap);            
        }
        
        for(PC_List__c PCList:[SELECT Name, BDM__r.Lastname FROM PC_List__c WHERE Name IN :PCNo]) {
            String Acc_Pc                      = (String)PCList.get('Name');
            ResultWrapper combinedResult        = mapPCToWrapper.get(Acc_Pc);
            combinedResult.Acc_BDM_Nachname     = (String)PCList.getSObject('BDM__r').get('Lastname');
        }
        
        resultList = mapPCToWrapper.values();
        
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have 2 options:

1. 'Easier to interpret' solution: create 3 loops instead of 2.
   1 loop over CampaignMember to collect all PCNo
   2 loop over PC_List__c to create a Map PCNo->BDM
   3 loop over CampaignMember to assign BDM to CampaignMember and populate the resultList
2. 'More efficient' solution: replace
   `Map<String, ResultWrapper> mapPCToWrapper = new Map<String, ResultWrapper>();`
   by
   `Map<String, List<ResultWrapper>> mapPCToWrapper = new Map<String, List<ResultWrapper>>();`

That way you can store multiple Campaign Members under 1 postalcode, and also assign the BDM to multiple Campaign Members. It will require some additional handling for the list, i.e. create a new list for the first CampaignMember, and also loop through that list when assigning BDM's.

The first loop will become something like:

```
for(Campaignmember CamM:[SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Salutation, Contact.Account.BillingPostalcode FROM Campaignmember WHERE CampaignId = :CamId and Status = 'selected']) {
    PCNo.add(CamM.Contact.Account.BillingPostalcode);
    ResultWrapper wrap              = new ResultWrapper();
    wrap.CampMem_Id                 = CamM.Id;
    wrap.CampMem_Firstname          = CamM.FirstName;
    wrap.CampMem_Lastname           = CamM.Lastname;
    wrap.CampMem_Salutation         = CamM.Salutation;
    wrap.Acc_Pc                     = CamM.Contact.Account.BillingPostalCode;
    if(!mapPCToWrapper.containsKey(wrap.Acc_Pc){
        mapPCToWrapper.put(wrap.Acc_Pc,new List<ResultWrapper>());
    }
    mapPCToWrapper.get(wrap.Acc_Pc).add(wrap);            
}
```

The second loop will become something like:

```
    for(PC_List__c PCList:[SELECT Name, BDM__r.Lastname FROM PC_List__c WHERE Name IN :PCNo]) {
        String Acc_Pc                      = (String)PCList.get('Name');
        for(ResultWrapper combinedResult : mapPCToWrapper.get(Acc_Pc)){
            
            combinedResult.Acc_BDM_Nachname     = (String)PCList.getSObject('BDM__r').get('Lastname');

            resultList.add(combinedResult);
        }
    }
```

(and remove the resultList = mapPCToWrapper.values();)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try the second solution, but this is very new for me. Could you provide me a sample how does this work?

Comment: Updated my answer. The rest you should be able to figure out by yourself :-)

Comment: Thanks, for your help. It looks good in debug mode, but I can't display the resultlist at my visualforce. <apex:repeat value="{!resultlist}" var="w">
 {!w.KampMem_Lastname}        
</apex:repeat> The debug show that content is in the resultlist, but the result will not appear :-(

Comment: The list is probably only filled after your page was rendered. I'd recommend opening a separate question for that, as to no pollute this thread.